# Basic JS script does not want to load in the HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to get the most basic thing possible to work and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <title>This Is Just a Dummy App</title>
</head>
<body>

  <button onclick="makeAlert()">Click here</button>

</body>

</html>
```

script.js, it's in the same directory as the HTML file

```
const makeAlert = () => { alert('Hey hey') };
```

The page does not want to load, period and there are no errors in the browser console.

UPDATE

This is part of Node.js app, without Express or anything and this is how it's configured to load HTML. I don't know if this is a factor here or not.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3001;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = req.url;

  if(url === '/') {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.write('something went wrong');
      } else {
        res.write(data)
      }
      res.end();
    })
  }
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into mine, and it works

Comment: Kinda silly, but happens. Maybe check if you spelled your `script.js` file correctly?

Comment: That's weird. This is part of a Node app, but the page loads fine if I take the use of this script out.

Comment: I added my code for starting Node server and loading HTML. Maybe this has something to do with it?

Comment: try adding a script inline, and check out what the current path is via the console?  Not sure how node works exactly but it's probably a pathing problem.  https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to

Comment: You mean copy the actual script into the <script> tag instead and test that out? Just did and it works this way. Yeah, perhaps something is not right with either the path naming, then.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine from a snippet, are you trying to run it from a server or just from the file system? Some browsers don't like running scripts from the file system. Get a development web server.

```js
const makeAlert = () => { alert('Hey hey') };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>This Is Just a Dummy App</title>
</head>
<body>

  <button onclick="makeAlert()">Click here</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's weird. This is part of a Node app, but the page loads fine if I take the use of this script out.